# Does google one tap sign up works when user is not logged into his google account?

Tags: google-identity

Below code works fine but when opened from an incognito windows console only shows

```
GoogleYolo loaded.
No credentials
```

```html
<html>
<head><title>My Yolo Login example</title>
<script src="/common.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://smartlock.google.com/client"></script>
 <script>
      

      const PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID =
          '*******-**********.apps.googleusercontent.com';
      const CONFIG = {
        supportedAuthMethods: [
          'googleyolo://id-and-password',
          'https://accounts.google.com'
        ],
        supportedIdTokenProviders: [{
          uri: 'https://accounts.google.com',
          clientId: PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID
        }],
 context:"signUp"
      };
      window.onGoogleYoloLoad = (googleyolo) => {
        console.log("GoogleYolo loaded.");
 var retrievePromise = googleyolo.retrieve(CONFIG);
        retrievePromise.then((credential) => {
         console.log(credential);          

        },
 (error)=>{
 if(error.type == "noCredentialsAvailable"){
  console.log("No credential");
  googleyolo.hint(CONFIG).then((credentials)=>{console.log(credentials);});} 
 });
      };
    </script>   

</head>


</html>
```

How can I know that user doesn't have a google account and redirect/take other action for him to login to his google account.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the product manager at Google for this library. We are working on some better support for users who are not signed in, but in the interim, when no Google Accounts are active and no credentials are available, you can simply show the traditional Google Sign-In button and have the user click to proceed through the flow to activate their Google Account in the browser.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

Comment: Thanks for the fallback. Please release a better solution to this sooner.

Comment: It would be nice if the yolo library opened a "sign into your google account" modal if it detects that the environment is supported, but the user is not signed into any account. Falling back to a separate library seems excessive for what has to be a common occurrence.

Comment: past 3 years by now. there is a newer solution?

Comment: Nothing new so far..Facebook is doing better here...

Comment: @Steven any plans to change this behavior?

Comment: nothing. thats just bad.

Comment: @Steven So the library you linked to is being discontinued. Is there still no solution for users who are not signed in with the new library?

Comment: If I allow the lib to render a button using the method google.accounts.id.renderButton, I'm able to sign in even in an incognito window. However if I create a button myself, and call the google.accounts.id.prompt method in an incognito window, nothing is displayed and the reason is opt_out_or_no_session. Sample of button rendered with the lib that works in incognito window: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview

Comment: thanks for posting the answer here. I am deving on android (not web). Could you please explicitly add this limitation somewhere on the official document? @steven Second question: Is  there any way to detect if the user hasn't logged in to the device to show the web login button?

Comment: @squirtgun Right, the new mandated google sign in flow is no longer wide-use friendly. If you try to invoke `prompt`, it fails outright for most people not using Chrome, and all the people of Chrome who have disabled those annoying site-wide login prompts that show up everywhere like annoying popup ads. The traditional (and GOOD) way is dying end of march 2023 :( so the only way to trigger the old flow (which is now limited in functionality), is doing `renderButton`. Ugh.

Comment: @IncredibleHat why in the world did Google bring a working solution to EOL when their replacement wasn't complete and:

1) janky at best
2) has terrible documentation
3) makes no improvement over the prior solution... you can tell I'm not frustrated eh? :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onGoogleLibraryLoad = () => {
  // initialize one-tap here
  google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: "YOUR_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    callback: handleCredentialResponse,
    itp_support: true,
    auto_selec: true,
    prompt_parent_id: 'g_id_onload',
    cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
    ux_mode: 'popup',
  });
  google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
    // if one-tap is not displayed show the google sign-in button (in private mode for example)
    if (notification.isNotDisplayed()) {
      console.log('not displayed');
      google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById('g_id_onload'), {
        type: 'standard',
        shape: 'rectangular',
        theme: 'outline',
        text: 'continue_with',
        size: 'large',
        logo_alignment: 'center',
        width: 300
      })
    }
  });
};

function handleCredentialResponse(googleResponse) {
  // do something after callback from Google
}
```

```html
<script defer async src='https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client'></script>
<div id='g_id_onload'></div>
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer. @Vladyslav Shchypanov .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).